# Change the active bootstrap tab on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the active bootstrap tab on the click of another button.

I have tried add id's to the tabs li and write custom jquery code.

```
$('#emailNotify').click(function () {
    $('#notify').addClass('active').attr('aria-expanded','true');
    $('#myacc').removeClass('active').attr('aria-expanded','false');
});
```

This code works fine on first click but it doesn't change back when I tried to click My Account tab again.

[image: Image of Tabs and Button]

Markup:

```
<ul class="content-list museo_sans500">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Change Password</a></li>
<li><a id="emailNotify" data-toggle="tab">Change Email Notifications</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Change Profile Picture</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please add the markup ?

Comment: I have added the markup. @DinoMyte

Comment: ' $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        active: 0      
  });' This the way I do it in jquery.  this would be first tab

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer are you using `data-toggle="tab"` for your tabs

Comment: @bigOTHER Yes, I am using data-toggle='tabs'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can change the active tab on the click event button with that:

```
$('#changetabbutton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mytabs a[href="#second"]').tab('show');
})
```

Here's a JSFiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ns0mdcf/

Answer (score 2):

You should use [twitter-boostrap way](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs) to change between tabs:

```
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); // Select first tab
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select last tab
```

or

```
$('#notify').tab('show'); // show notification tab
```

Comment: I have added this on button but it is only changes active tab and not change it tab content   :   <li><a id="emailNotify" onclick="$('#notify').tab('show');">Change Email Notifications</a></li>

Comment: for that, use `<li><a href="#notify" data-toggle='tab' >Change Email Notifications</a></li>`. but for button **Edit Details**, use `$('#myacc').tab('show'); `

Comment: Sorry for asking silly details. basically, I want to change the active tab and content to Notifications tab on the click of Edit Details button. I have added  onclick="$('#notify').tab('show');" on Edit Details button. but this is only changes the active tab selection but no tab content.

Comment: you should define tab content using `href` or `data-target` in #notify definition. like `<li><a href="#content_notify">Profile</a></li>` where `content_notify` is the id of the content